# Configure nginx to set the content type from the URL only when there is an allowed user

Tags: nginx, http-headers, access-control, content-type

I implemented a `location` configuration like this (`legituser` is set by a map lookup):

```
location / {
  if ($legituser = 0) {
    return 200 "you are not allowed to access this url, please do bla bla bla ...";
  }

  more_set_headers "Content-Type: $arg_mimetype";

  root /media/s3content;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Remark: I know that http status might seem odd in this scenario but I want to make sure the users get proper information and in the real scenario the return contains much more than shown here.

If the user is legit, I want to return files that are stored on S3. The `Content-Type` needs to be overwritten by the value of `...?mimetype=...` which I do by using `more_set_headers`.

This works quite well, except when I'm not legit and open for example `http://server/some/path/somefile?mimetype=image/png`. Then I get a png file which consists of only the text sent by `return`.
It became clear to me that `return` doesn't work like `return` in a programming language like Java and doesn't exit the location block.

In a programming language I would do something like this:

```
if( legituser == 0 ) {
  setMimeType( "text/html" );
  return( 200, "you are not ..." );
} else {
  setMimeType( $arg_mimetype );
  try_files ...
}
```

But this is not how nginx works and I'm absolutely not sure if I'm running into the usual problem if using [if in a evil way](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Would this work and be "OK" / proper style ?

```
set $ct $arg_mimetype;

if( $legituser = 0 ) {
  set $ct 'text/html';
}

more_set_headers "Content-Type: $ct";

if( $legituser = 0 ) {
  return 200 "you are not ...";
}

root /media/s3content;
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

Comment: From your link, "would it be 'OK'" block is evil.  It says the only thing you can do in an `if` is `return` or `rewrite` and you do a `set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How can I add header conditionally in nginx configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467671/how-can-i-add-header-conditionally-in-nginx-configuration) on StackOverflow  this should be:

```
map $legituser $mimetypeheadervalue {
    0        'text/html';
    default  $arg_mimetype;
}

location / {

  more_set_headers "Content-Type: $mimetypeheadervalue";

  if ($legituser = 0) {
    return 200 "you are not allowed to access this url, please do bla bla bla ...";
  }

  root /media/s3content;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

In the map, if the `$legituser` is zero it uses  `text/html` and otherwise fills in with the value in your other variable.   Then you use the newly created variable from your map to set the header.